# Multiple remote objects

Tags: c#

Хорошо ли использовать много объектов MarshalByRefObject, которые будут элементами списка возвращаемые из плагина или есть какойто лучший способ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нехорошо. Типы, наследующиеся от MarshalByRefObject, используются только для передачи данных через границу. Как только вы получили от кого-то эти данные, преобразуйте их в свои типы (заведите какой-нибудь класс типа ListItem) -- переложите все данные, и в списке отображайте элементы вашего типа.

Это убережет вас от лишних изменений в коде при изменении контракта.